# Run .NET Core 2.1 + Angular + IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

I am trying to bring up a application written in ASP.NET CORE 2.1 and Angular 7.
I am using IIS in Windows Server 2016 and installed .NET Core 2.1 Runtime & Hosting Bundle for Windows.

After publishing the solution in Visual Studio 2017, web.config has this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\Diarias.Web.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: b3f72ccb-207e-461c-b822-2152a37a2311-->
```

But after trying to start the website, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The SPA default page middleware could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not found, and no other middleware handled the request.
Your application is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to switch to the Development environment.
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Diarias
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Please share the code of Startup.cs file. Also, what is the `outputPath` in angular.json file under options?

Comment: Mohsin, thank you. In Startup.cs file, it was pointing to the wrong directory:
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });